# Find out which Unicode

Tags: mysql, service, unicode, openstack

Is there a way to find out which encoding my MySQL Service is using?

And how can I change it?

I've a little problem with the packstack installation of openstack

Comment: Are you telling me that there is more than one Unicode? Why didn't they name it Multicode, then?

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, ucs2 and utf-8 are unicode encodings, **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html**

Comment: Those are not "Unicodes". Those are encodings, and in MySQL neither of them truly covers the Unicode character set. "Unicode" is the name of a standard, not a generic term for an encoding.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, it was typo by me, I am totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> SHOW variables LIKE '%character_set%'; // provide information of character set of db
mysql> show collation
```

use

```
 mysql> `SET character_set_client = utf8` // your character set value
```

[Mysql Collation and Character set help](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-charsets.html)